# Cannot start my static file hosting server in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an very simple ASP.NET vNext just wanted to be a static file server. I had used `kvm upgrade` to install the latest version and below is my `project.json`.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Helios" : "0.1-alpha-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems": "0.1-alpha-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Http": "0.1-alpha-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": ""
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener server.urls=http://localhost:22222"
    },
    "configurations" : {
        "net45" : {
        },
        "k10" : {
            "System.Diagnostics.Contracts": "4.0.0.0",
            "System.Security.Claims" :  "0.1-alpha-*"
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my `Startup.cs`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I ran `kpm restore` I got the error said

```
Unable to locate Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles >= 0.1-alpha-build-0402
Unable to locate Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics >= 0.1-alpha-build-0623
Unable to locate Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting >= 0.1-alpha-build-0519
Unable to locate Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener >= 0.1-alpha-build-0469
```

Below is the result of `kvm list`.

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture Location
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------
       0.1-alpha-build-0421 svr50   x86          C:\Users\me\.kre\packages
       0.1-alpha-build-0472 svr50   x64          C:\Users\me\.kre\packages
       0.1-alpha-build-0472 svr50   x86          C:\Users\me\.kre\packages
  *    0.1-alpha-build-0496 svr50   x86          C:\Users\me\.kre\packages
```

I think I have `0.1-alpha-*` installed but why `kpm restore` told me cannot find.

Comment: Do you have the AspNet vNext MyGet feed (https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/master/NuGet.Config#L4) configured?

Comment: Worked! I need to put this `NuGet.config` into the parent folder of my website. Please move this to answer so that I can mark, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the AspNet vNext MyGet feed (github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/master/NuGet.Config#L4) configured?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a version to the StaticFiles dependency