# ASP.NET VNext Debugging MVC Source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I followed the [blog post of Imran Baloch](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/aspnet-vnext-debugging-mvc-source) where he shows how you can debug into ASP.Net MVC VNext.

I used a VM in Azure where Vs 2014 is installed.
[image]

I created the global solution folder and placed a global.json file in it where I specified the folder containing the current MVC source cloned from https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src.
When I try to compile the solution I get a lot of errors because of missing references.

[image]

Did anybody try out the method proposed in the blog post? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like a NuGet issue, is the solution set to retrieve missing NuGet packages during build? If it is, perhaps something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115923/cannot-start-my-static-file-hosting-server-in-asp-net-vnext might help?

Answer (score 8):

I'm shooting blind here because adding the sources to global.json works fine for me.

Try adding a NuGet.config file to your solution with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <packageSources>
     <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/" />
     <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
   </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Also, try doing running `kpm restore` at the root of your solution folder.

If this doesn't help, please add a little more information like KRE version, what is in your `<user profile>\.kre` or `<user profile>\.kpm` folders

Answer (score 2):

add 'http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2' to tools -> options -> nuget package manager -> package sources

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just ran:
git clone https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc.git
kvm upgrade
kpm restore

Then I opened the mvc solution in vs2014 ctp2 and it opened and compiled correctly. I think that your project.json has version numbers in there which do not match the version numbers used in your cloned version of mvc. Microsoft changed the version numbers some time ago.

The cloned version of mvc on my box uses Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems version 1.0.0-*, which is not included in the mvc source and is a package reference. It also used Miccrosoft.AspNet.Mvc.Common version "", which is a source code reference. You could try to adjust your project.json to match the numbers.

HTH,
Bart

Answer (score 0):

And perhaps to answer yourself to your question you may need to read this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Mixing different versions (yes, ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 is still a moving target!) may lead to very annoying results. Read and see.