# Default vNext template on Visual Studio 2014 CTP2 cannot find the references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS 2014 CTP2 and tried to create a vNext project and it just won't build. It cannot find the references.

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Try adding a nuget.config file like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984866/asp-net-vnext-debugging-mvc-source

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci: Thanks, that helped a bit but then I kept having problems with Nuget. I ended up going back to VS 2013. Thank you again.

Comment: Can you please tell me what other issues you have?

Comment: Also in the `Output` in Visual Studio check the "Package Manager log" section (it's in the dropdown list). That might have some diagnostic info that could tell you what's going on.